# I want to know the operands for starting the indicator from a particular bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

i am a newbie to scripting and coding world and pine script is the first language i am learning and i need your help

i have a script already written for my indicator in pine script version 4 but now i want to convert it into version 5.

i am having problem converting one line into version 5 and i have bolded that line in the script below.

what i want to do is this: "i have asked for user inputs to start the midas curve from a particular bar number, now i just want to write one line of code which makes the indicator start calulating and plotting from one bar number before than the number inputed by the user.

i.e, if the user says that he wants to start the curve from 1000 bar number, than the script should start calculating from bar number 999"

here is the script:

```
study("Midas", overlay=true)

startBar=input(title="Starting Bar Number",minval=1,maxval=100000,defval=20)
priceType=input(title="calculate using 1:hl2 2:high 3:low 4:hlc3",minval=1,maxval=4,defval=1)


**start = (n==startBar-1)**

p = iff (priceType==1,hl2,
            iff(priceType==2,high,
                iff(priceType==3,low,hlc3)
            )
        )


v = na(volume) ? 1 : volume

cumV = cum(v)
CumPV = cum(p*v)

startV = valuewhen(start,cumV,0)
StartPV = valuewhen(start,CumPV,0)

midas = (CumPV-StartPV)/(cumV-startV)


plot(midas, color=navy,linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an automatic function to convert all pine version to pine v5 [image]

By the way, it seems like you only need one "=" in that line, like this:

```
start = startBar-1
```

or you can even do this in the input line

```
startBar=input(title="Starting Bar Number",minval=1,maxval=100000,defval=20) - 1
```